# PHP Mailer Function not working

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I am new to PHP and have a form that sends mails. The following is the PHP code and i get the message
"Message body empty message could not be sent.

mailer error: 
"
I have been searching on google whole day of what the issue might be but have not been able to figure it out.

I am not understanding the part "Message body empty". I checked the $mail.body and it has the value.

```
<?php

require_once("class.PHPMailer.php");

 $mail = new phpmailer();
 $mail->issmtp();      // set mailer to use smtp
 $mail->host = "smtp.office365.com";  // specify main and backup server
 $mail->smtpauth = true;     // turn on smtp authentication
 $mail->username = "noreply@test.com";  // smtp username
 $mail->password = "test123"; // smtp password

 $mail->from = "noreply@test.com";
 $mail->fromname = "no reply";
 $mail->addaddress("johndoe@test.com", "John Doe");

 $mail->wordwrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
 //$mail->addattachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
 //$mail->addattachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
 $mail->ishtml(true);                                  // set email format to html

 $mail->subject = "here is the subject";
 $mail->body    = "this is the html message body <b>in bold!</b>";
 $mail->altbody = "this is the body in plain text for non-html mail clients";
echo $mail->subject;
 try{
 if(!$mail->send())
 {
  echo "message could not be sent. <p>";
  echo "mailer error: " . $mail->errorinfo;
  exit;
 }

 echo 'after mail send';
 }
 catch(exception $e) {
  echo 'caught exception: ',  $e->getmessage(), "\n";
}

echo "message has been sent";
?>
```

Also I have deployed in windows server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you suppressing errors? `// echo 'caught exception: ',  $e->getmessage(), "\n";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Never test for an error you can't handle...

Comment: @MikeW So, why have it in there in the first place? ;-) (*I can't handle the truth*)

Comment: Many mail services refuse to send mail when the reply address doesn't match the address of the logged in account.

Comment: the error, you can't handle the error

Comment: I feel like Jack Nicholson

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was testing few things and I had commented it, I have changed it back. I dont get an exception.

Comment: The manual on PHPmailer states `new PHPMailer()` and you're using `new phpmailer()` I don't know if the letter-case will make a difference. @user2480288

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried with PHPMailer(), but i get the same result.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with deployed in windows server? Are there any settings that i need to do? I have set up the SMTP server and port in php.ini

Comment: You're running this on your own machine or a hosted server? If it's on your own machine, is sendmail/SMTP setup, and properly configured?

Comment: That area I don't have expertise on. I run everything off a hosted server.

Comment: I am running on a windows server.

Comment: Many host providers don't allow you to send from an email that has not been created in your account example (Cpanel)..

Comment: @Othman I didnt get you.

Comment: This is all horribly wrong because you don't seem to know that PHP is case-sensitive for property and variable names. Base your code on the examples provided with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<h2>Feedback Form</h2>
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
  <?php
} else {    // the user has submitted the form
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"])) {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("webmaster@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: above code will work. But you will need working SMTP server running web hosting server